# Signal and Noise with every day examples

Tags: time-series

Yesterday a friend asked me what is a signal and noise. When I described him he wasn't satisfied and he told me to give him an everyday example. What kind of example would you use to describe them as simple as possible?

Comment: To down-voter - Why the down-vote? Based on one's curiosity and interest I conclude nothing is silly . And till the time you are asking it means you are seeking for more insight into that subject, it is considered good. In real life, how many people understand the difference asked in this question? Engineers included.

Comment: One we all experience is noise on cell phone conversations.  The signal is the voice of the person you are talking to, the noise is everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some "real world" examples:

1. Hide and Seek.
2. Where's Waldo?
3. Needle in a haystack
4. Discovering exoplanets
5. Camouflage
6. ICBM launch detection
7. Predator/Prey interactions

Answer (score 0):

The signal is the truth. The noise is what distracts us from the truth.

https://www.predig.com/whitepaper/reducing-signal-noise-practice
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio